# wavy division sign wanted

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I would like to find or create a math relation symbol that resembles a division sign, except that the horizontal bar would instead be a tilde (\sim).  Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Just to go safe: Did you search already in [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21)

Comment: yes, and failed.

Comment: I am not an expert for math mode. In text mode something should be possible with kerning, perhaps also `\sim` and `\colon`? Let’s wait for our TeXperts.

Comment: this looks to me a lot like unicode U+223B (homothetic); there's also U+2A6B (tilde operator with rising dots).  these would be in the `stix` or `xits` fonts.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Yes, it is the “Homothetic”. It is also in other Open-/Truetype fonts included.

Comment: That's the one!  Trouble is, afaict, I would have to switch to a completely different font set to use this character.  I'm using amsfonts and a pretty vanilla LaTeX setup overall.  Any advice?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here, I build a generic form with stacks, and then use `scalerel` package's

```
\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}
```

and `\mathchoice` to make it work for the various mathstyles.  The optional arguments to `\genericform` are the distances the under and over dots are vertically shifted.   They can be tweaked to suit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\stackMath
\def\ccdot{\scalebox{1.15}{$\SavedStyle\cdot$}}
\def\genericform#1#2{\stackunder[#1]{\stackon[#2]{\SavedStyle\sim}{\ccdot}}{\ccdot}}
\def\altdiv{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\mathchoice%
  {\genericform{-2.5pt}{-1.5pt}}%
  {\genericform{-2.5pt}{-1.5pt}}%
  {\genericform{-2.0pt}{-1.1pt}}%
  {\genericform{-1.4pt}{-0.8pt}}%
}}}
\begin{document}
$A \altdiv B ~~A \div B$\par
$\scriptstyle A \altdiv B ~~A \div B$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle A \altdiv B ~~A \div B$\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Note: Modifications to scalerel package discussed below have been implemented into `scalerel` V1.6 (10 MAR 2014).  New lengths that scale with the mathstyle, inside of `\ThisStyle{}`, are available as `\LMex` and `\LMpt`.**

This answer got me thinking about an improvement to my `scalerel` package.  In particular, the `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` syntax allows me to access glyphs in the current mathstyle (because it internally performs a `\mathchoice`), but my answer above still requires an additional `\mathchoice` because lengths (even scalable ones like "ex") do not scale with the current mathstyle.

What I need is for `\ThisStyle{}` to additionally create a length that *does* scale with the current math style.  So I do that below, and call it `\LMex` (Local Mathstyle "ex").  It is 1ex in `\displaystyle` and `\textsstyle`, 0.7ex in `\scriptstyle` and 0.5ex in `\scriptscriptstyle` (inside the argument of `\ThisStyle`).

In so doing, I can avoid an inefficient nesting of `\mathchoice`es and avoid the use of my `\genericform` altogether, if I express the length shifts of my stack in terms of multiples of `\LMex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\stackMath
%%%%% scalerel MODIFICATION
\makeatletter
\newlength\LMex
\renewcommand\ThisStyle[1]{%
  \ifmmode%
    \def\@mmode{T}\mathchoice%
      {\edef\m@switch{D}\LMex=1ex\relax#1}%
      {\edef\m@switch{T}\LMex=1ex\relax#1}%
      {\edef\m@switch{S}\LMex=.7ex\relax#1}%
      {\edef\m@switch{s}\LMex=.5ex\relax#1}%
  \else%
    \def\@mmode{F}%
    \edef\m@switch{T}#1%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
%%%%% END scalerel MODIFICATION
\def\ccdot{\scalebox{1.15}{$\SavedStyle\cdot$}}
\def\altdiv{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{%
  \stackunder[-.6\LMex]{\stackon[-.45\LMex]{\SavedStyle\sim}{\ccdot}}{\ccdot}}}}
\begin{document}
$A \altdiv B ~~A \div B$\par
$\scriptstyle A \altdiv B ~~A \div B$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle A \altdiv B ~~A \div B$\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this worked beautifully, without having to change over all of my fonts.  (i used the first version above.)

Answer (score 17):

The following example deals with the following issues:

- The symbol automatically changes its size according to the current math style.
- Correct bounding box.
- The dots are centered around the math axis.

It makes the following assumptions:

- `\sim` is centered around the math axis.
- The dot is located right above the baseline.

It follows `\div`:

- The dots are slightly larger, the example uses a scale factor of `1.15`.
- The lower dot is slightly below the baseline, the example puts the dot
  a quarter of its height below the baseline and shifts the upper dot by the same amount to the top.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mydiv}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@mydiv{}%
  }%
}
% #1: math style
% #2: unused
\newcommand*{\@mydiv}[2]{%
  \sbox0{$#1\vcenter{}$}%
  \sbox2{\scalebox{1.15}{$#1.\m@th$}}%
  \sbox0{%
    \raisebox{-.25\ht2}{\rlap{\copy2}}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr2\ht0-\ht2+.25\ht2\relax}{\copy2}%
  }%
  \sbox2{$#1\sim$}%
  \rlap{\copy2}%
  \hbox to \wd2{\hfil\copy0\hfil}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% Comparison
\[
  A \div B \mydiv C
\]
% Automatic adaptations to math style
\[
  A \mydiv B^{A \mydiv B^{A \mydiv B}}
\]
% Show bounding box
\[
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
  A \mathbin{\fbox{$\mydiv$}} B
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 16):

The way of definition is ugly but, it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\mydiv}{%
  \mathbin{\text{%
    \mathsurround=0pt
    \ooalign{%
      \hidewidth\vphantom{$\div$}\raisebox{.95ex}{\scalebox{1.2}{.}}\hidewidth\cr
      $\sim$\cr
      \hidewidth\vphantom{$\div$}\raisebox{-.05ex}{\scalebox{1.2}{.}}\hidewidth\cr
    }%
  }}%
}
\begin{document}
  $A\mydiv B$ $A\div B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is neat! Can I name this symbol? I'd go with `\dancingdiv`. `:)` *Update:* oh wait, there's a better one: `\wibblywobblydivysymbol`. `:)`

Answer (score 6):

this looks to me a lot like unicode U+223B (homothetic); there's also U+2A6B (tilde operator with rising dots). these would be in the `stix` or `xits` fonts.

Speravir confirms the identify of U+2238 and also points out in a comment that it is included
in other opentype and truetype fonts (see below for his edit).

it's *not* found either in the comprehensive symbols list, or by `detexify`.

it's usually not desirable to replace entire fonts to make just one or two missing
symbols available.  that situation is addressed by this question:
[Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386).

---

*(Edit by Speravir after requested by Barbara, cf. comments)*

Without trying to be complete I can confirm, that these Open- or Truetype fonts contain the symbol “Homothetic”:

- [STIX Fonts](http://www.stixfonts.org/),STIX, STIX Math & STIX MathJax
- [XITS Fonts](https://github.com/khaledhosny/xits-math)

Both already named by Barbara and included in TeX distributions. For the following I did not look, whether they are available as TeX package (actually I know for some of them, that they are).

- Arial Unicode MS (Microsoft/Agfa Monotype)
- Cambria & Cambria Math (Microsoft/Monotype)
- [DejaVu Fonts](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page)
- [GNU FreeFonts](https://www.gnu.org/software/freefont/)
- [GNU Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html), but rather ugly like most glyphs of this font
- [Junicode](http://junicode.sourceforge.net/)
- Segoe UI Symbol (Microsoft)

Comment: you have found the right character, but i don't know how to use it without changing over all of my fonts, which i'd rather not do.

Comment: @BobHarper -- i've added a link to a question that might be helpful.

Comment: @Speravir -- please do add the names of the fonts you know contain this symbol, and thanks for the info.  if you could also mention whether they require xetex/luatex, or have support for use with pdflatex, that would be a plus.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Only for DejaVu fonts a Type1 version is available, as far as I see. But I do not know, whether this version contains the symbol in question.