# "Square hat" accent

Tags: accents

I have seen in a book the following "square hat" symbol to denote the discrete Fourier transform:
[image: DFT notation]

I would like to use the same symbol, but I cannnot find the corresponding command. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Try `\overbracket{u}`; see p. 60 of [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). (You will need `\usepackage{mathtools}`.)

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one you can tailor and which fits to the argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\rlwd{.4pt}
\def\rlht{1.1pt}
\def\shatvrule{\rule{\rlwd}{\rlht}}
\def\shat#1{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}%
  \stackon[0pt]{\stackon[1pt]{\ensuremath{#1}}{%
    \shatvrule\kern\wd0\kern-\rlwd\kern-\rlwd\shatvrule}}%
    {\rule{\wd0}{\rlwd}}%
}
\begin{document}
$\shat u(\omega,t) = \shat{XYZ}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `1pt` is the gap below the hat to the letter, which can be changed, the `\rlht` is the height of the vertical strut, and `\rlwd` is the rule thickness.

If you need it to work across math styles, here is a slight variation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\rlwd{.4pt}
\def\rlht{1.1pt}
\def\shatvrule{\rule{\rlwd}{\rlht}}
\def\shat#1{%
 \ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackon[0pt]{\stackon[1pt]{\ensuremath{\SavedStyle#1}}{%
    \shatvrule\kern\wd0\kern-\rlwd\kern-\rlwd\shatvrule}}%
    {\rule{\wd0}{\rlwd}}%
 }%
}
\begin{document}
$\shat u(\omega,t) = \shat{XYZ}$

$\scriptscriptstyle\shat u(\omega,t) = \shat{XYZ}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if I wanted to get really fancy, I could introduce variable rule height, thickness and stacking gap, all of which scale with the math style, as described at the bottom of this answer: [wavy division sign wanted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163926/wavy-division-sign-wanted/163984#163984).  Without reiterating that code, the result would look like

[image]